# How to test web application performance ?

Tags: performance, web-applications

We have a web application (uisng `ASP.Net` and `Alaska WAA`)  which was designed many years ago (not by my team). It  mainly uses `Alaska’s Xbase++`  code  via WAA to query Database and generate `HTML` response.  Earlier it was running on win 2003 and IIS 6. Now this web application was migrated to new environment .. Windows 2008 and IIS7 (we did that migration).

This application uses `Mysql` as Backend and shows some images stored in shared drive. The problem is that the Website’s performance is not satisfactory. The pages are taking more than 10-12 sec to load (which was not the case with earlier setup). Now, we want track down down the root cause of the delay. We are suspecting the performance of DB server and shared drive. How we can confirm this ? IS there any tool which can help us to track down the cause for ths delay ? 
(`Alaska WAA` – Web Application Adapater—It is a kind of application server  which will run the Xbase++ code on server. `IIS` will request `WAA` (like CGI application) and `WAA` will do the Server side processing.. like getting details from DB, generate HTML response and retun to `IIS`) 
Or Xbase++ code base is very huge and we cannot go through that code to fine tune the queries. 
Is there any way to test the DB server Performance, Shared Drive Performance, `CGI` performance.. ?

Answer (score 0):

First question would be whether the new platform is specifically Windows Server 2008 and IIS 7.0, or perhaps is Windows Server 2008 R2 with IIS 7.5. There are notable file performance issues in Windows Server 2008 and these may well be contributing to your performance issues as a result of the migration. Migrating to Windows Server 2008 R2 (if that's not where you are) may be enough to resolve these issues.

However, within the realm of tools that can help isolate the location and causes of web performance issues, you may find some value from our [Web Performance Monitor](http://www.solarwinds.com/web-performance-monitor.aspx). A 30-day free trial is available, and that may be sufficient to isolate and resolve this issue.